# Graphics3D not rendering Ball as a filled object

Tags: graphics, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and persisting through 11.1.1 or later**

---

*Mathematica* V10 introduced the built-in function `Ball`. The documentation page, [`Ball`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ball.html), says

- `Ball` represents a filled ball $\{x|\left\| x-p\right\| \leq r\}$.The region is $n$ dimensional for point $p$ of length $n$.

But it doesn't look filled when I render one with `Graphics3D`.

```
Graphics3D[{Ball[3]}, PlotRange -> {{0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}, {0, Automatic}}]
```

[image: graphics]

Is the documentation misrepresenting `Ball` or is there a bug in `Graphics3D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. I reported the problem to Wolfram tech support and I got the following confirmation:

> I have filed a bug report with the development team and thank you very much for giving us feedback.

Answer (score 13):

I suppose this is a minor bug.  I say "minor" because I think `Ball` was introduced as part of the geometric region functionality that's really meant to support the FEM framework and it works well in that context.  Thus, we can use it to visualize a sold ball like so:

```
DiscretizeRegion[Ball[], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: My question is about how `Graphics` behaves when given `Ball`, so I don't see this answer as relevant.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, you asked if it was a bug. I replied "this is a minor bug" with explanation as to why I consider it to be minor and suggested a workaround.

Comment: It's not a work-around. A descretized region can't be combined with other graphics in a diagram rendered by `Graphics3D`.

Comment: @m_goldberg `Show[{DiscretizeRegion[Ball[],{{0,1},{0,1},{0,1}}],Graphics3D[Sphere[]]}]` works fine for me. I really don't understand your object to the answer at all. Regardless, the assertion that it's not relevant seems patently false.