# How can I get one octant of a ball?

Tags: graphics3d, regions, geometry

I tried to get a 1/8 of a filled sphere using the built-in function `Ball`.

[Someone has already asked a similar question years ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60978/graphics3d-not-rendering-ball-as-a-filled-object)

It seems like Mathematica still has this bug.

Can anyone tell me how to use `Ball` to get an octant?

Here is a my very simple code:

```
Graphics3D[Ball[], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion[Ball[], {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}]` uses `Ball`....

Answer (score 2):

In V11.1, which introduced `Region`, you can do:

```
Region @ RegionIntersection[Ball[], Cuboid[]]
```

[image: solid]

This a true octant.

```
RegionDimension @ octant
```

> `3`

```
Volume @ octant
```

> `π/6`